# SAS SQL Pass-Through Facility Specifics for ODBC

Tags: sql-server, sas, pass-through

First time to use  SQL Pass-Through and couldn't figure out how it works.

```
libname myl odbc datasrc=AAA;
```

I tried this

```
proc contents data=myl.mytable;run;
```

It works exactly the same as

```
proc contents data=AAA.mytable;run;
```

So the `libname` statement works?

But when I tried this no luck.

```
proc sql;
connect to ODBC(datasrc=AAA);
execute (delete from Oit.d1 where datepart(Date) >= '08Mar2014'd) by ODBC;
disconnect from ODBC;
quit;
```

Error shows

```
ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Did I miss some arguments?

Comment: The only information I can find about the server is the host name obtained from right clicking the icon in the server list in SAS.

Comment: Try adding the SASTRACE option - 

`options sastrace='d,' sastraceloc=saslog nostsuffix;`

And take a look at the log in both cases.

Comment: Try to set options in gui, the latter %put should return the settings you "clicked":`proc sql;
   connect to odbc (prompt);
quit;
%put &sqlxmsg;`

Comment: Take a look at the section of [this pdf](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/415-2013.pdf) dealing with explicit pass through and see if that's helpful.  In particular, I would try the example they give of making a query (any query, just something silly) and tell SAS to generate explicit pass through source for you; then if it runs, look at that source and see what connection information it uses.

Comment: I think this error can also be the result of using a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit SAS or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following:

- This error message is usually caused by a typo in the `datasrc=` statement, or failure to setup the DSN in `Control Panel->ODBC Data Sources`.
- Be sure that the value you entered (`AAA` in your example) is exactly how the name appears in `Control Panel->ODBC Data Sources`.
- Check that when you click test in the ODBC settings, it can connect successfully.
- Finally, be sure that your ODBC connection is setup as a `System DSN` and not a `User DSN` if you will be running the SAS job from an account different to your windows login account.  System DSNs are visible to all users on the computer, not just the user that created that ODBC connection.

This is how my ODBC passthrough statements normally look for a simple query:

```
/* mySQL example */
proc sql noprint;
  connect to odbc (datasrc=myDSN user=myusername password="mypassword");

  create table sqlo as 
  select *
  from connection to odbc
  (
  select * from database.table limit 1
  )
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: How to setup as a `system dsn`?

Comment: When you go into `Control Panel->ODBC Data Sources`, you are presented with a list of tabs.  There will be a tab for `System DSN`, just choose that tab, and then click the 'Add' button.